# Stack of views or generate on need?

Tags: performance, qt, qwidget

Let's suppose, I'm creating a image editor, something like Photoshop, but simplier in Qt.

I got next problem - I have list of items and I can select only one of them at a time. Each item got `QWidget` which should be shown in `MainWindow`. The question is - should I create them(widgets) when I select item or should I just manage visibility of this widgets. Currently, I got the second solution - when item selected, I set the visibility of `QWidget` to `true`, and hide current widget. What is better in case of performance? I'm new to Qt, don't which practice is better to use in such case.

For better understanding - attaching a picture with sidebar and place for QWidget(blurred woman)

Disclaimer: It's not a opinion question - I'm asking about best practice in Qt and performance in each case. Thanks.[image]

Comment: You can use QListWidget populated with QListWidgetItem's with your custom widgets assigned to them. QListWidget can make sure you have only one item selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html) and [QListWidgetItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html) controlling the [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html):

```
// Stacked widget
QStackedWidget *pStackedWidget = new QStackedWidget();

// Creating widget list
QListWidget *pListWidget = new QListWidget();
connect(pListWidget, &QListWidget::itemSelectionChanged,
    [pStackedWidget, pListWidget]() {
        pStackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(
            pListWidget->currentItem()->data(Qt::UserRole)
        );
    }
);

// Populating widget list with items
QListWidgetItem *pItem = new QListWidgetItem();
pListWidget->addItem(pItem);
pItem->setItemWidget(pItem, pWidget);
pItem->setData(Qt::UserRole, 0 /* widget index on stacked layout */);
```

Visibility of the widgets on the right is controlled by the QStackedWidget. Corresponding widget index is set upon selection change in the QListWidget.
Widget index can be stored in custom user data assigned to corresponding QListWidgetItem.

Comment: Thanks again for idea with QListWidget, but the main key is that I got QWidget binded to my custom QListWidgetItem as additional one - that is shown on the right side, where the blurred woman shown. Should I create them and manage their visibility or should I create them on purpose?

Comment: @htzfun For that you can use QStackedWidget that keeps all your widgets on the right. When selection in the list changes you can set corresponding current widget index. You can associate widget index via custom user data set on QListWidgetItem.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you again. Could you move this comment to the answer part and I'll accept it.

Comment: @htzfun I've updated the answer, but it's just an example. Depending on your application you also have to take care about ownership of your widgets and the way they created and deleted in run time.